# .htaccess rewrite problem?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

how can i write a rewrite rules and conditions, to change the format of my url:

www.example.com/topic.php?topic=love

into

www.example.com/love

i have been searching, but i dnt seem to understand!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ topic.php?topic=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ topic.php?topic=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /topic.php?topic=$1
```

For more information on the syntax, check out http://regular-expressions.info.